# Set directory permissions with inheritance during application installation?

Tags: windows, windows-installer, file-permissions

I found [a thread on the Microsoft Forums](http://www.microsoft.com/communities/newsgroups/en-us/default.aspx?dg=microsoft.public.platformsdk.msi&tid=cefe69f5-082e-4bce-b866-f3ad55457e5f&cat=en_US_58b1458d-1bc1-4445-a50b-450ea40fa7ab&lang=en&cr=US&sloc=en-us&m=1&p=1) where the answer tells how to set directory permissions using the LockPermission table. I tried it, but it doesn't seem to set the inheritance for any of the subdirectories. I need to be able to set the permissions for a particular folder that I create and have those permissions be inherited by all of the files and directories within and beneath it. Is there a way to do this without having to add a line in the LockPermission table for each and every directory (and file) that I want to affect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either see if the MsiLockPermissionsEx support in MSI 5 handles this (and is an acceptable dependency for you as currently it's only available on Windows 7), or you can implement custom support. The LockPermissions support available in earlier versions of Windows Installer has the limitation you describe (and others).

Comment: I was hoping that wouldn't be the case. We have to support as far back as XP, so anything that's only available in Windows 7 is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking to know the joys and pains of using MsiLockPermissionsEx, here is a tutorial, some best practices and a helper script. The helper script extracts SDDL from existing system resources - so you just use Regedit and Windows Explorer to set permissions and the helper script extracts them for you.

The article also discusses the challenge of supporting XP and Windows 7 permissions with a single package.

You can check it out here: http://csi-windows.com/toolkit/csigetsddlfromobject

Comment: This actually looks like a good way to go. If we didn't already find an alternative work-around (read Windows calls in custom actions) to do what we want, we might have been able to use this solution.